# Perfect pairing for finitely generated free A- modules (Harthorne Chapter III Theorem 5.1)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the proof of Theorem 5.1(d)(chapter III) Hartshorne states a natural pairing of $H^0(X, O_{X}(n))$ with $H^r(X, O_{X}(-r-1))$. Now I know the definition of perfect pairing for A-modules (let's take M,N) which tells us the isomorphism between M and Hom(N,A), this  I can relate to the $n < 0$ as then it follows trivially.

But I don't get the proof for non-negative $n$ as I'm not sure how to use the definition of pairing of modules.

Comment: The proof doesn't depend on $n$, so it's a little puzzling why you're having trouble with one part but not the other. Can you explain more about what your issue is? (Also, check your twists, it's not quite right as written right now.)